Do I need to use @QuarkusTest annotation for unit tests in a Quarkus application?
I'm working on a Quarkus application and trying to understand the best practices for testing. I know that Quarkus provides the @QuarkusTest annotation for integration tests, which sets up a Quarkus application context and provides useful features for testing the integration of components.
However, I'm primarily focusing on unit tests where I don't need the full Quarkus runtime. In these cases, do I still need to use @QuarkusTest, or is there a more appropriate way to write unit tests in Quarkus?
Should I continue with this approach, or are there benefits to using @QuarkusTest even for unit testing? Are there specific scenarios where using @QuarkusTest is beneficial for unit tests?

If you don't need the Quarkus runtime (all it provides), then you should not be using @QuarkusTest - just use plain old JUnit tests with whatever other test extensions you like

There is also @QuarkusComponentTest for unit tests.

That's a good point!

Mockito.mock is not working, but io.quarkus.test.Mock is working. So the @QuarkusTest annotation seems to be needed.
